# How to avoid or reduce back-pain by adjusting the handlebar and seat of 19.5" MTB?

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, handlebars, seatpost

I'm 6' 3" long, having 45 inches of waist-Toe length. I bought Trek 3500, 19.5" sized frame bicycle two months ago. I've been experimenting with the handlebar and seat positions(Forward n Backward) to achieve comfort,to avoid stress in the back and shoulders,since the purchase.I'm riding it,with the seat post touching the minimum insertion mark already. But i couldn't achieve it yet. Please help me out in this, Bike is my mode of transport as well as i take long rides of 40-60 Kms seldom(Once or twice in a week). Should i ride this bicycle or upgrade to 21" bike. Help me here!

Comment: 1) 19.5" sounds small for someone who's 6'3".  2) You can get a longer seat post (up to a point).

Comment: Thanks bro, is longer seat post enough to achieve riding comfort? Because handlebar stays at the same position(i.e. at the max position right now). At first, even in the long rides, i dint feel discomfort. I'm facing it after two months. Anyway, i'll get longer seat post as you suggested and will try it.

Comment: In my opinion most handlebars are too low from the factory to begin with and should (almost) always have an extension installed at the bike shop.  This is one major reason why about 80% of bikes are never ridden more than 100 miles.

Comment: A good Idea Boss.! :) I'll try to bring modification in that way now. I think it's gonna give a lot of change. Then i'll post my experience after changing it. Thank you.

Comment: Bro, I had all modifications to my 3500 bike. Considering your suggestions, I'm now upgrading my bike to Trek Gary Fisher 29er Wahoo. Now i'm going for the correct frame size of 21". What do you say about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the recommended procedure for adjusting the fit of my bike?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3963/what-is-the-recommended-procedure-for-adjusting-the-fit-of-my-bike)

Answer (score 2):

I'm 6'2" and my [Giant XTC 29er XL (22")](http://www.giant-bicycles.com/en-us/bikes/model/xtc.29er.2/9031/48896/#geometry) fits me perfectly. I would definitely upgrade. There's more to the geometry than just the height of the saddle that could affect the way your body fits (or contorts to) the frame.

Comment: Yeah bro, you are right! If it is inevitable to upgrade then i would definitely do that...!! Thanks for the opinion bro.

Comment: I'm also upgrading my bike to Gary Fisher 29er Wahoo(21") by Trek. I think it would be an awesome bike. What do u say?

Comment: A friend has one and seems content with the purchase. That size will fit you a lot better.