# Why do I do the "saddle shuffle" when riding?

Tags: bike-fit, saddle, riding-position

I was browsing some time trial videos on YouTube and came across a video on saddle shuffling, and I've been noticing that I do the same saddle shuffle a lot when riding hard.  Did not really know it was a problem until I saw a [video](http://youtu.be/2sYUfzHzYaU) about it.  Is this common among riders?  My seat is correctly positioned too and it's perfectly level. I wonder how common this is...

*To anyone who can't see the video:* The problem is that a rider will, over time, shuffle forward on the saddle as they ride, every so often pushing themselves back so they're squarely on the saddle.

**Edit:** About me:  I'm 5'6 about 145lb and ride a Specialized [Allez Apex](http://www.specialized.com/us/en/bc/SBCProduct.jsp?spid=62277&scid=1101&scname=Road). I use clipless pedals and have received a [BG Bike Fit](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3549/bike-fitting-experiences). The bike size is a 52.  I would consider myself an aggresive rider.

**Update:** So I thought I would update you with some tweaks I've done so far. I went to my LBS and purchased a shorter stem so I'm not leaning forward as much. I also measured my seat and myself [(sit bones)](http://www.specialized.com/specs/spec.jsp?speccode=bodygeometrysaddles&tablewidth=400&cellwidth=350) and it showed that my seat was too narrow, though, I have been measured before and have always been told the seat was good (my other two bikes were the same). I was suggested to try the [Romin](http://www.specialized.com/us/en/bc/SBCEqProduct.jsp?spid=64276) or [Avatar](http://www.specialized.com/us/en/bc/SBCEqProduct.jsp?spid=64272) saddles. The look of the Romin seems like it will keep me from moving forward as much. I plan on testing the seats out in a trainer and around town. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: could not add the tag: saddle shuffle

Comment: It sounds like this question is more of a poll; have voted to close. If, rather than asking people who also does this, you want to ask *why*, that'd be a good question.

Comment: updated.  sorry about that neil.  yeah, i'm wondering why i do this.  Someone i ride with says it because of my push and pull momentum, but that does not really explain much

Comment: Nice edit! That's interesting; now I understand the problem a lot better. (I think I do the same thing, actually. Looking forward to seeing the answer.) My close vote will expire naturally in time.

Comment: Added some text into the question for anyone who can't see the video, but if I'm still misunderstanding the problem, please revert my edits in a heartbeat!

Comment: @NeilFein looks good to me.

Comment: Some more information about about your bike would be helpful.

Comment: @freiheit - Good point. The *ideal* awesomeness here would be, if possible, a picture of fady on the bike. But I'm guessing road bike. The saddle is level and presumably at the correct height, but what about reach? Bar tilt?

Comment: yeah, i would love to show pictures of me doing the bike fit, but i don't have those with me (at work)

Comment: Frame size, etc? On a road bike, like the Allez, its usually a function of a saddle which is too high. But reach, or an incorrect frame size can be causing it, too. If you've been fit, by a trained and skilled fitter, then it's hard to say without more details.

Comment: After reading this post I was paying attention to my own shuffling on my ride this morning. I noticed it only happens when I'm putting in the maximum effort and it feels more like I'm trying to get some extra power by moving back slightly. So I'm wondering how much is a fit issue and how much is just physics.

Comment: Seems to me, from watching the video, that this is something that very, very well-trained, highly skilled cyclists do on bikes that have been professionally fit to the point of obsession.  Therefore I can't see that it's something that a amateur could hope to avoid while riding in an aggressive manner.  The torque of pedaling will tend to drive the cyclist forward, and the extreme prone position will tend to make it harder to resist the forward motion with the arms.  It happens.

Answer (score 5):

It all depends on your saddle. As someone who has just been enlightened, some saddles are supposed to be pointed a bit nose up. Take the brooks flyer for instance, it is not the front that is supposed to be level. It is the back making the front point a bit upwards. I think of it less of a seat then a hammock.

I have also had a saddle that was a left over from my fat days that provided extra back support. Because of it's design for bigger behinds, and me lacking one for the first time in a long time, I kept sliding forward which was hurting my taint (for lack of a better word).

Try angling your seat up a bit or maybe moving it forward a bit on the rails. Play around with the fit and see what kind of results you get. If all else fails you can go to your LBS and ask them to take a look at it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Saddle width needs to match the width of your "sit bones" plus maybe a centimeter. Get yourself measured and get the correct width saddle.

Sorry. You'll have to find a LBS with a measuring device, or keep researching to find your width. There no relation to the width of your butt - it's the bones that you sit on that are on the saddle.

Generally, if the saddle is too narrow you'll shift around as described above.

The start point for the saddle is exactly level, centered on the rails. so , start there, and adjust in small increments.

Hope these few tips help!