# Bike fitting in the UK

Tags: road-bike, bike-fit, uk, hybrid-bike

As an keen but casual touring cyclist I'm interested in getting a little more competitive and also keeping myself comfortable over longer distances. So I'm considering getting professionally fitted, as [from others' experiences](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3549/bike-fitting-experiences) it sounds good. What should I look for in a fitter and where in the UK (preferably the South) can I find a good one? I'm wary of going somewhere that will be mostly focused on selling me new parts or a new bike.

Also, would the measurements be in any way transferable to another bike? I ride a [Marin San Alselmo](http://www.bikepedia.com/quickbike/BikeSpecs.aspx?Year=1999&Brand=Marin&Model=San%20Anselmo&Type=bike#.UKdOYxK9pyA) and a Thorn Tandem, plus I'm considering something properly race-roadie as my N+1.

**EDIT:** I know there are a few sub-questions here and many people won't be able to answer them all, but I'd also be appreciative of partial answers.

Comment: I was recommended someone based in Southampton. But have not used them myself - friend of a friend. If that is sufficiently close to you drop me a line and I will hunt out their name.

Comment: I'm leaving this question as is for historical reasons, but the "recommend a specific place to have this done" part of the question is off-topic now as a product recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Mountain Trax](http://www.mountain-trax.com/page/24/bikefitting). They have specifically gone down the route of bike fit and spent some time training in the US with the developer of the system. They are one of the best bikes shops in the south and I would class their service before and after sales as the best I have encountered. 
They are based in Barkham, Wokingham and can easily be reach from the M3 or M4.

Comment: Thanks, I'll get in touch with them and see what they offer.

Answer (score 0):

I have also discovered [Bike Dynamics](http://bikedynamics.co.uk/) in Leamington Spa and [Bike Science](http://www.bike-science.com/precision-bike-fitting-c-295.html) in Bristol.

I'm planning to contact them as well as the other suggestions and see what they offer, updating this answer with my experiences.